# Laravel Mockup Cache Redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis, mockups

I have problem with mockup Redis and tags cache I get error 
Error: Call to a member function get() on null

```
$cache = Cache::shouldReceive('store->redis')->shouldReceive('tags')
                ->once()->with('tripUpdate')
                ->shouldReceive('get')
                ->once()->with('trip_update_' . 1)
                ->andReturn(json_encode([]));
```

I want try mockup this code :

```
       $tag = Cache::store("redis")->tags("tripUpdate");
       $tripUpdateCache = $tag->get('trip_update_' . $tripId);
```

Comment: Please consider adding code to produce a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).